# List files in directory over socket Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serversocket, python-3.8, listdir

How can you send a command to list files in a directory over a socket?

```
#
# Write a script that connects to 'localhost' port 10000
# You then need to send a command to list the files in the /tmp directory
#

import socket, os, json

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", 10000))
cmd = json.dumps(os.listdir("/tmp"))
sock.send(cmd.encode())
print(sock.recv(1024).decode())
```

It gives me absolutely no output at all. What gives?

Comment: The error is probably in your `sock.send(cmd)` line. `cmd` should be the bytes object. `os.listdir` returns a list of strings. First you have to combine the list. Then convert it to bytes. Try `sock.send('\n'.join(cmd).encode('utf8'))`

Comment: I hit enter prematurely and then revised the line. Does the revised line do that as well?

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: You should really say what line number it is complaining about. Is it line 4? I suspect listdir needs an str, so get rid of the 'b'.

Comment: Oh! If you pass a bytes object to listdir, it returns a liist of bytes object. So if you keep the `b'/tmp'`. You may be able to get away with `sock.send(b'\n'.join(cmd))`.

Comment: I tried that, and it got rid of the errors.  However, now it produces no output at all, and if I do `sock.recv(1024)`, it just says `b''`.

Comment: What's on the other end of this socket connection?  *That's* what is receiving the directory listing, and would be providing whatever reply that this code prints out.

Comment: The environment in which I'm attempting to carry out the instructions given to me is set up so I can't (to the extent of my knowledge) see the server side of the socket connections I make.

Comment: I suggest you look at [file transfer protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), there is already [a library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) built into python that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is trying to find a different answer, this works too and is easier for anyone to understand:

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 10000))
clientsocket.send('ls /tmp'.encode())
data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
print(data)
```

The command `ls /tmp` lists the files in the /tmp directory.